# How do I access available connections for Mongodb replicaset for mongoose v6?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

we used to be able to access available connections in mongodb replicaset via:

```
const primaryConnections = mongoose.connection.db.s.topology.s.coreTopology.s.replicaSetState.primary.s.pool.availableConnections.length
```

However, after upgrading to mongoose v6.2.10, this became undefined.

Tried `mongoose.connection.db.s.client.topology.s.servers.s.pool` (there are a number of internal metrics e.g. ConnectionPoolMetrics) which look like:

```
{
    txnConnections: 0,
    cursorConnections: 0,
    otherConnections: 0
}
```

However, they don't seem to be reflecting the same values as what I'm seeing on my terminal when running mongod server locally. Not sure if this is the right metric to check?

Some additional information:

- nodejs@18.12.0
- mongoose@6.2.10
- mongodb@4.2.2

[EDIT] I found an internal metric under `mongoose.connection.db.s.client.topology.s.servers.s.pool[Symbol(connections)]` that seem to point to what I was looking for, it looks like:

```
{
    _head: 25,
    _tail: 16,
    _capacityMask: 31,
    _list: [...] // Lists stats for each connection
}
```

How should I interpret `_head`/`_tail`/`_capacityMask`?

Comment: Is `{ useUnifiedTopology: true }` on your MongoClient.connect?

Comment: Nope it is not.. But would there be other stats available if that flag is true?

Answer (score 0):

I found some getters on the underlying mongodb connection pool object - to access those:

```
let availableConnections = 0;
mongoose.connection.db.s.client.topology.s.servers.forEach(server => {
     availableConnections += server?.s?.pool?.availableConnectionCount ?? 0;
});
```